# How to input phone country code with flag in registration form?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a registration form for user there is a field for telephone number. i want to auto select country code with small flag. what will be the scrip for this region. Please help me. How can i use it in my form? Please help me

thanks

this is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@countries  = { "United States" => "+1", "Bangladesh" => "+88", "Switzerland" =>     "+41"    };
</script>

<form  method="post" >
<select> 
<option value="select country">Select</option>
<option value="@countries">@countries</option>
</select>

<form>
```

Comment: Please post what have you tried so far.

Comment: you will need jQuery for this.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot insert a `<img>` in `<option>` tag with `<select>`. So you can go for a jQuery plugin.

DOWNLOAD

http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown

https://github.com/marghoobsuleman/ms-Dropdown

DEMO

http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/index.html

Comment: i did not get any download option there. can send me proper link?

Comment: https://github.com/marghoobsuleman/ms-Dropdown was linked on the page that Anup linked to.